# Coq: usage of `PartialOrder` typeclass

Tags: typeclass, coq

I am trying to define lexicographic ordering on strings over posets, but I'm not completely sure how to use the `PartialOrder` typeclass.

```
Require Import List RelationClasses.

Fail Inductive lex_leq {A : Type} `{po : PartialOrder A} : list A -> list A -> Prop :=
  | lnil: forall l, lex_leq nil l
  | lcons: 
      forall (hd1 hd2 : A) (tl1 tl2 : list A),
        hd1 <= hd2 -> (* error *)
        (hd1 = hd2 -> lex_leq tl1 tl2) -> 
        lex_leq (hd1 :: tl1) (hd2 :: tl2).
```

Partial output:

```
The term "hd1" has type "A" while it is expected to have type "nat".
```

Clearly `<=` is the wrong notation to use here; I'm wondering how I can obtain an ordering relation from my `po` instance.

Comment: In this case the relation is named `R`, so `R hd1 hd2` will work; you could of course define your own notation in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can bind the names explicitly to make things more obvious. Before we can do this we need to tell Coq not to complain about unbound variables using the `Generalizable Variables` command:

```
From Coq Require Import List RelationClasses.

Generalizable Variables A eqA R.

Inductive lex_leq `{PartialOrder A eqA R} : list A -> list A -> Prop :=
  | lnil: forall l, lex_leq nil l
  | lcons: 
      forall (hd1 hd2 : A) (tl1 tl2 : list A),
        R hd1 hd2 ->
        (hd1 = hd2 -> lex_leq tl1 tl2) -> 
        lex_leq (hd1 :: tl1) (hd2 :: tl2).
```

You can find more information in the manual ([here](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#implicit-generalization)).